# Emacs key problem

Tags: ssh, emacs, cygwin

I am using Cygwin to connect to an Ubuntu installation, and for some reasons my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> for the help has been remapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>.

When I actually type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>,<kbd>h</kbd> I get the error:

> No operation mapped for Ctrl + c <DEL>.

There was a key mapping for ctrl + h to ctrl + delete in the init.el, now I have deleted it but still ctrl + h acts as a ctrl + DEL.

How can I reset this?

Comment: What terminal are you using on the Windows machine? E.g. rxvt under X, xterm under X, standalone rxvt, standalone mintty, native Windows console, Console2, …

Comment: I'm with Gilles, it's probably a setting in the application you are using to connect, rather than in Cygwin itself, or Ubuntu, or Emacs.

Comment: I am using Cygwin and I am connecting through ssh

Answer (score 3):

Your `C-h` key is mapped to `C-DEL`.  Try this:

```
(define-key key-translation-map [?\C-h] [?\C-?])
```

Or you can change your terminal so it sends `C-DEL` (aka `C-?`) instead of `C-h` for the Backspace key.  To do that:

```
stty erase '^?'
```

More information here:

- [Ctrl+h causing backspace instead of help in emacs on cygwin | Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/375864/ctrlh-causing-backspace-instead-of-help-in-emacs-on-cygwin)
- [Backspace Key | Emacs Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BackspaceKey)